# Securing a Bitnami Postgresql Database on Google Cloud

Tags: postgresql, security, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have deployed a basic Ruby on Rails app on Google Cloud App Engine. I also deployed a Bitnami Postgres instance on compute engine. They're all in the default network group. However, I'm worried that the postgresql instance has a very weak firewall setting. The firewall setting is:

```
postgresql-1-tcp-5432

Network
default

Priority
1000

Direction
Ingress

Action on match
Allow

Targets
Target tags         postgresql-1-tcp-5432

Source filters
IP ranges           0.0.0.0/0

Protocols and ports
tcp:5432
```

Can someone advise how I can secure my database? I'm new to networking and google cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Well Stephen, there are several ways to do it.

If you have all your resources in the default network [use network tags](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/add-remove-network-tags) to apply firewall rules to the respective objectives.

```
gcloud compute instances add-tags [INSTANCE_NAME] --tags tag-1,tag-2
```

So your Ruby could be app, and your postgress db. In that case you can apply some the firewall rules to the respective VM. And allow only ingress to the db VM from your Ruby VM.
__________________-

The other options are prefered as setting up a proxy. You can find more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely)